# Oracle SQL -- Finding count of rows that match date maximum in table

Tags: oracle, oracle11g, aggregate, aggregate-functions, having

I am trying to use a query to return the count from rows such that the date of the rows matches the maximum date for that column in the table.

Oracle SQL:  version 11.2:

The following syntax would seem to be correct (to me), and it compiles and runs.  However, instead of returning JUST the count for the maximum, it returns several counts more or less like the "HAIVNG" clause wasn't there.

```
Select ourDate, Count(1) as OUR_COUNT
from schema1.table1
group by ourDate
 HAVING ourDate = max(ourDate) ;
```

How can this be fixed, please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know if I understand what you want. Try this:

```
Select x.ourDate, Count(1) as OUR_COUNT
from schema1.table1 x
 where x.ourDate = (select max(y.ourDate) from schema1.table1 y)
group by x.ourDate
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use:

```sql
SELECT MAX(ourDate) AS ourDate,
       COUNT(*) KEEP (DENSE_RANK LAST ORDER BY ourDate) AS ourCount
FROM   schema1.table1
```

or:

```sql
SELECT ourDate,
       COUNT(*) AS our_count
FROM   (
  SELECT ourDate,
         RANK() OVER (ORDER BY ourDate DESC) AS rnk
  FROM   schema1.table1
)
WHERE  rnk = 1
GROUP BY ourDate
```

Which, for the sample data:

```sql
CREATE TABLE table1 (ourDate) AS
SELECT SYSDATE FROM DUAL CONNECT BY LEVEL <= 5 UNION ALL
SELECT SYSDATE - 1 FROM DUAL;
```

Both output:

> | OURDATE | OUR_COUNT |
> | --- | --- |
> | 2022-06-28 13:35:01 | 5 |

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=13884715b3890e0cfe911bfa5bf7e3da)*

Comment: Very nice; I selected the other naswer because it came in earlier.

Comment: @MTO I'm curious why would you not use dense_rank instead of rank. This way if the OP wanted they could find second, third.... highest if the requirement changed. Wouldn't it not be a matter of using rnk=N? I'm not questioning your expertise rather my limited knowledge of rank vs dense_rank. Thanks for taking the time to respond

Comment: @Pugzly `DENSE_RANK` and `RANK` both function identically when you want the 1st rank. So, for this use case, it does not matter which of the two you use. `RANK` is less to type though.

Comment: @MTO thanks got it. I appreciate your time, response and clarification

Answer (score 1):

One option is to use a subquery which fetches maximum date:

```
select ourdate, count(*)
from table1
where ourdate = (select max(ourdate) 
                 from table1)
group by ourdate;
```

Or, a more *modern* approach (if your database version supports it; 11g doesn't, though):

```
select ourdate, count(*)
from table1
group by ourdate
order by ourdate desc
fetch first 1 rows only;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
You can use this SQL query:

select MAX(ourDate),COUNT(1) as OUR_COUNT
from schema1.table1
where ourDate = (select MAX(ourDate) from schema1.table1)
group by ourDate;
```